# Key error adding two Pandas data-frames together

Tags: python, pandas

Frames `df1` and `df2` that I'd like to add together to make `df3`.  Partial data-frames (as they are quite large) are as follows

`df1`:

```
            total_pnl_per_pos          invested    
date 
2015-03-17           0.330533     145790.529585   
2015-03-18          -0.132040     152116.458134       
2015-03-19           0.189508     141114.361229         
2015-03-20           0.346906     323712.355051        
2015-03-21          -0.004500     149999.909424
```

`df2`:

```
            total_pnl_per_pos     invested  
date                                                                
2015-03-16          -0.009346   3843277.00  
2015-03-17          -0.025422   4495925.00  
2015-03-18          -0.093223   4233412.00  
2015-03-19          -0.144945   4340475.00  
2015-03-20          -0.030945   6107379.00
```

I'd like `df3` to be `df1` + `df1` and to look like:

```
            total_pnl_per_pos      invested
date        
2015-03-16          -0.009346       3843277
2015-03-17           0.305111    4641715.53
2015-03-18          -0.225263   4385528.458
2015-03-19           0.044563   4481589.361
2015-03-20           0.315961   6431091.355
2015-03-21            -0.0045   149999.9094
```

Note that df1 and df2 are indexed by date and do not necessarily have the same dates in each data-frame.

I have tried to use:

```
df3= df1.set_index('date').add(df2.set_index('date'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

and

```
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('date').sum().reset_index()
```

I however get a `KeyError: 'date'` error when I try the two different solutions.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `date` here is used as index it cannot be accessed as a column. Try `df3= pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().groupby('date').sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `date` is already index. In other words, you cannot assign `date` as index **twice**. Thus below would work:

```
df3 = df1.add(df2, axis='index', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
            total_pnl_per_pos      invested
date                                       
2015-03-16          -0.009346  3.843277e+06
2015-03-17           0.305111  4.641716e+06
2015-03-18          -0.225263  4.385528e+06
2015-03-19           0.044563  4.481589e+06
2015-03-20           0.315961  6.431091e+06
2015-03-21          -0.004500  1.499999e+05
```

Hope this helps.